# How to for loop strings into a single element to a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, beautifulsoup

I'm going through each url page, and want to have all of the titles of all of the links from each page in their own respective cell in my content list. However, I believe I'm missing something obvious but I'm quite a novice. I know at the moment that every iteration creates a new cell in my list, so I'm trying to prevent that.

```
for url in url_list:
        open_page = driver.get(url)
        html_source = driver.page_source
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source, 'html.parser')
        links = soup.find('div', {'class': 'body'})
        content = []
        for link in links.find_all('a'):
            temp = link.get_text()
            content.append(temp)
        print(content)
```

Comment: please give the current output and the output that you want

Comment: `content = [a.text for a in soup.select('a')]`, but better edit your question and post sample of HTML or URL and desired output.

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you're getting a list of lists in `content`. Try `.extend(temp)` instead of `.append(temp)`.